# Connecting geom_line with dodged points within a point grouping, within a facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, facet-wrap, geom

I can't seem to get geom_path to connect **dodged** points within a facet_wrap with grouped variables. The path lines remain vertical instead of connecting observations. I want to keep the points dodged as a way to show time trajectory within a treatment. Example data and ggplot script below.

```
df <- data.frame (Treatment  = c("Drill_Herb", "Drill_Herb", "Drill_None", "Drill_None", "Herb_None","Herb_None", "Herb_Drill", "Herb_Drill"),
                  Comparison_Combo = c("Drill_Herb_TO_Drill_None", "Drill_Herb_TO_Drill_None", "Herb_None_TO_Herb_Drill", "Herb_None_TO_Herb_Drill"),
                  Ratio = sample(1:8, 8, replace=FALSE),
                  Year = c("2017", "2021","2017", "2021","2017", "2021","2017", "2021"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Treatment, y=Ratio, shape=str_wrap(Year,25), 
  linetype=str_wrap(Treatment))) +
  facet_wrap(~Comparison_Combo, drop = TRUE, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1) +
  geom_point(size=3.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.55))+
  geom_path(aes(group=Treatment), lwd=1, 
  position=position_dodge(width=0.55))
```

Output:

[image: Image of output plot]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Quinten I put code for creating a reproducible dataframe in the question. Sorry, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2**:

You could create an extra column with the x-axis position in numeric way to have the values dodged. You could use two x aesthetic columns for both the layer and `geom_point` and `geom_line`. Using `scale_x_continuous` to have the continuous axis to dodge the values and create labels like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Treatment2 = c(0.8, 1.2, 2.8, 3.2, 1.8, 2.2, 3.8, 4.2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=Ratio, shape=Year, linetype=factor(Treatment))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Treatment2), size=3.5)+
  geom_line(aes(group = Treatment, x = Treatment2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4), labels = c("Drill_Herb", "Herb_None", "Drill_None", "Herb_Drill")) +
  facet_wrap(~Comparison_Combo, drop = TRUE, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Edit**

You should add a column that shows the combination of the points you want to connect like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Treatment2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=Ratio, shape=Year, linetype=factor(Treatment2), group = factor(Treatment2))) +
  facet_wrap(~Comparison_Combo, drop = TRUE, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1) +
  geom_point(size=3.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.55))+
  geom_path(lwd=1, 
            position=position_dodge(width=0.55))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

You could use `group` in your aesthetics like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Treatment, y=Ratio, shape=str_wrap(Year,25), 
               linetype=str_wrap(Treatment), group = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~Comparison_Combo, drop = TRUE, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1) +
  geom_point(size=3.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.55))+
  geom_path(aes(group=Treatment), lwd=1, 
            position=position_dodge(width=0.55))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The issue is that I would prefer if the points were dodged within a treatment, and the connecting line would show the time trajectory from 2017 to 2021. Exactly like in my reference figure, but the lines should connect the points, instead of being vertical.

Comment: Hi @ChadKluender, Aah I see, you need a column which shows an unique combination for your linetype.

Comment: Hi @ChadKluender, Please see updated answer above!

Comment: Thanks Quinten, this is still not the answer I'm looking for. I'm trying to connect the individual year symbols within the treatments within a comparison combo. For example, drill_none 2017 to drill_none 2021. We did this on the first example you created, but the point jitter was removed. It seems that every time I create a grouping variable the jitter is removed. Even when I create a unique ID for treatmentXcomparison combo